# Catch the POST Request Response and the Redirected URL from XMLHTTP request with VBA

Tags: vba, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to catch a Response to a POST Request using XMLHTTP using the code below

```
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim htmlEle1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlEle2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim URL As String
Dim elemValue As String

URL = "https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/?search=500004064"


    XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLPage.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
        
    For Each htmlEle1 In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
        Debug.Print htmlEle1.className
       If htmlEle1.className = "styles__SCFileModuleFooter-e6rbca-1 kUUNkj" Then
          
          elemValue = Trim(htmlEle1.innerText)
          If InStr(UCase$(elemValue), "CONSTITU") > 0 Then
                'Found Value
                Exit For
          End If
       End If
    Next htmlEle1
```

The problem is that I can't find the ClassName "styles__SCFileModuleFooter-e6rbca-1 kUUNkj", because I notice that when I manually insert the value (500004064) in the search box of the URL : https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/, the Web Page generates addicinal traffic and turns up at an end point URL : https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832, where that className can be found in the Request ResponseText.

My goal is to use the First URL to retrieve the Duns number '453060832', to be able to access the information in the ResponseText of the EndPoint URL. And to catch Duns Number, I need to find a way to get the Endpoint URL, or try to get The POST request response below, and get that value using JSON parser:

```
{'TotalResults': 1,
 'NumberOfPages': 1,
 'Results': [{'Duns': '453060832',
   'Vat': '500004064',
   'Name': 'A PANIFICADORA CENTRAL EBORENSE, S.A.',
   'Address': 'BAIRRO DE NOSSA SENHORA DO CARMO,',
   'Locality': 'ÉVORA',
   'OfficeType': 'HeadOffice',
   'FoundIn': None,
   'Score': 231.72766,
   'PageUrl': '/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832'}]}
```

I'm not being able to capture what is really happening using the  XMLHTTP Browser request, that seems to be the below steps:

1. navigate to https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/?search=500004064
2. Webpage generates additional traffic
3. Amongst that additional traffic is an API POST XHR request which
   returns search results as JSON. That request goes to
   https://www.informadb.pt/Umbraco/Api/Search/Companies and includes
   the 500004064 identifier amongst the arguments within the post body
4. Based on the API results the browser ends up at the following URI
   https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832

Can someone help me please, I have to do it using VBA.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The website makes a POST request to https://www.informadb.pt/Umbraco/Api/Search/Companies with `Content-Type: application/json` and this body `{"Page":0,"PageSize":5,"SearchTerm":"453060832","Filters":[{"Key":"districtFilter","Name":"Distrito","Values":[]},{"Key":"legalFormFilter","Name":"Forma Jurídica","Values":[]}],"Culture":"pt"}`. Note that your original search term is in the JSON. That request is the first you need to make, forget about loading the search page itself.

Comment: The response is `{"TotalResults":1,"NumberOfPages":1,"Results":[{"Duns":"453060832","Vat":"500004064","Name":"A PANIFICADORA CENTRAL EBORENSE, S.A.","Address":"BAIRRO DE NOSSA SENHORA DO CARMO,","Locality":"ÉVORA","OfficeType":"HeadOffice","FoundIn":null,"Score":229.91116,"PageUrl":"/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832"}]}`. Note the DUNs number, the VAT ID, and the `PageUrl` value.

Comment: This is probably already everything you need. No need to parse through HTML at all. You have the VBA code for a GET request; the code for a POST request with some JSON data in the body is almost identical. You will be able to find examples for this. Getting the needed data out of the response is not difficult, either. There are JSON parsers for VBA, but you could probably get by with a string search if you only want e.g. the VAT ID.

Comment: Please @Tomalak I need your help. I'm no expert in VBA. I'm given my first steps in web scraping.. I'll appreciate if you could show me the easy way to achieve one of my goals with vba, both the JSON response, or the endpoint URL.
I'm struggling with this for more than 3 weeks. Show me the code to achieve that, please.
My best regards

Comment: I've posted a minimal example that does exactly what I described above. You could have gotten to that point on your own. If that's already what you need, good. If it's not, please try to work from the example and make the necessary modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small example how to POST data to your website using VBA, and how to use bare-bones string processing to extract data from the result, as outlined in my comments above.

```
Function GetVatId(dunsNumber As String) As String
    With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        .open "POST", "https://www.informadb.pt/Umbraco/Api/Search/Companies", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send "{""Page"":0,""PageSize"":5,""SearchTerm"":""" & dunsNumber & """,""Filters"":[{""Key"":""districtFilter"",""Name"":""Distrito"",""Values"":[]},{""Key"":""legalFormFilter"",""Name"":""Forma Jurídica"",""Values"":[]}],""Culture"":""pt""}"
        
        If .status = 200 Then
            MsgBox "Response: " & .responseText, vbInformation
            GetVatId = Mid(.responseText, InStr(.responseText, """Vat"":""") + 7, 9)
        Else
            MsgBox "Repsonse status " & .status, vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim vatId As String

vatId = GetVatId("453060832") ' => "500004064"
```

For a more robust solution, you should use a JSON parser and -serializer, something like https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON.

Comment: Very much obliged @Tomalak. But what I realy need is the oposit; send the Vat and get the Duns number ".453060832". Thats because, afer that, I'll send a "GET" to the URL "https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832" to get more data from Html Document based on that number. 
What do you think I'll need to Alter in your code?
I know How to use JSON parser that you mentioned.
Thank you for all the help

Comment: @LEOPOLDO What I think is that you need to meditate over this task a bit more. I gave you code that *almost* does what you need. Search for one thing, extract the other. What you have to do is very *very* similar to what my code does. Read the code. Understand what it does. You will see what you need to change.

Comment: Can you please explain this line of Code, please?

`"{""Page"":0,""PageSize"":5,""SearchTerm"":""" & dunsNumber & """,""Filters"":[{""Key"":""districtFilter"",""Name"":""Distrito"",""Values"":[]},{""Key"":""legalFormFilter"",""Name"":""Forma Jurídica"",""Values"":[]}],""Culture"":""pt""}"`

Comment: @LEOPOLDO What does `"something " & variable & " something"` do? (Let's not make this a VBA 101 course, the comments are a horrible medium for this and it is a bit out of scope, too. Your question shows code at the same level that my answer has, you really should be able to figure all of this out.)